# Bootstrapping Hibernate in Grails G-Func functional tests

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails, grails-orm, functional-testing

I am trying to write automated functional tests for our Grails-based REST API using *[G-Func](http://grails.org/plugin/functional-test)* framework.

I did not have any problems with GET tests.  However, POST tests pose a serious challenge that I am unable to solve.  The problem is that after posting a request I need to verify that the database has been modified appropriately, and I would like to do it using GORM.

(the code and output below contain only the salient fragments)

**Take 1:**

```
package com.mycompany.api

import com.grailsrocks.functionaltest.*

class MyDomainObjectFunctionalTests extends APITestCase {

  void test1() {
    println MyDomainObject.count()
    ....
```

Run it with:

```
grails test-app functional: com.mycompany.api.MyDomainObjectFunctional -echoOut
```

Output:

```
| Failure:  test1(com.mycompany.api.MyDomainObjectFunctionalTests)
|  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [com.mycompany.data.MyDomainObject]
was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of 
a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
```

**Take 2:**

```
package com.mycompany.api

import com.grailsrocks.functionaltest.*

class MyDomainObjectFunctionalTests extends APITestCase {

  void test1() {

    HibernateDatastoreSpringInitializer init = new HibernateDatastoreSpringInitializer("com.mycompany.data")
    // com.mycompany.data is the package where the domain objects live

    init.configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", 'none')
    init.configuration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", 'true')
    init.configuration.setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", 'myschema')

    def dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(myDbUrl)
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")

    init.configureForDataSource(dataSource)

    println MyDomainObject.count()
    ....
```

Output:

```
Hibernate: select count(*) as y0_ from myschema.my_domain_object this_
ERROR 14:49:34:463 util.JDBCExceptionReporter
Table 'myschema.my_domain_object' doesn't exist
```

The table name is incorrect: it's supposed to be *myDomainObject*, not *my_domain_object* - we are using a custom Hibernate naming strategy.

(By the way, the database connection is fine: if I use the connection object from *dataSource* and write a manual SQL query against *myDomainObject* table it works).

So now I try to pass the custom naming strategy to Hibernate:

**Take 3:**

```
package com.mycompany.api

import com.grailsrocks.functionaltest.*

class MyDomainObjectFunctionalTests extends APITestCase {

  void test1() {

    HibernateDatastoreSpringInitializer init = new HibernateDatastoreSpringInitializer("com.mycompany.data")

    init.configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", 'none')
    init.configuration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", 'true')
    init.configuration.setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", 'myschema')

    init.configuration.setProperty("hibernate.naming_strategy", 'com.mycompany.data.OurNamingStrategy')

    def dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(myDbUrl)
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")

    init.configureForDataSource(dataSource)

    println MyDomainObject.count()
    ....
```

I also add debug prints to *OurNamingStrategy.classToTableName*:

```
package com.mycompany.data

import org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

class OurNamingStrategy extends ImprovedNamingStrategy {

  @Override
  public String classToTableName(String className) {
    ...
    println 'Table name for class ' + className + ': ' + tableName;
    return tableName;
  }
  ...
```

Output:

```
...
Table name for class MyDomainObject: myDomainObject
...

Hibernate: select count(*) as y0_ from myschema.my_domain_object this_
ERROR 14:49:34:463 util.JDBCExceptionReporter
Table 'myschema.my_domain_object' doesn't exist
```

So, it seems that Hibernate does take into account the custom naming strategy, however it ditches it when issuing the query.

At this point I am stuck.  Any suggestions how I can make this work?

Grails version 2.4.4

Comment: i think you might want to use https://github.com/alkemist/grails-remote-control/

Comment: @cfrick: I've taken a look. I do not understand how it would help me.  I also tried Geb, but I kept running into problems of generating the HTPP requests that are powerful enough for our purposes (e.g. with custom request headers, etc.)  grailsrocks at least helps with that latter problem

Comment: when running the functional tests, you are basically on the client-side of the world.  all the services, gorm, ... are not available. the remote control helps you to setup/assert things on server side. but this of course would only help, if that what you are describing in your question are all just symptons/workarounds for that problem. i might have misunderstood your question

Comment: @cfrick: yes, server-side assertions is essentially what I need.  I did not get the impression that that's what Grails Remote Control is doing.  I'll take a closer look

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it's a bug in `HibernateDatastoreSpringInitializer`.  I examined the code and while I did not pinpoint the exact location of the bug I was able to come up with a workaround:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder

...

void test1() {

    // HACK!!! GORM naming strategy workaround
    GrailsDomainBinder.NAMING_STRATEGIES['DEFAULT'] = new OurNamingStrategy()

    HibernateDatastoreSpringInitializer init = new HibernateDatastoreSpringInitializer("com.mycompany.data")
    ...
```

It seems that due to the bug GORM does not grab the right naming strategy object (which gets stored in `GrailsDomainBinder.NAMING_STRATEGIES['dataSource']` ), but rather the default object.  By overriding that entry I achieve the desired behavior.